# Comparar diferença entre valores da mesma coluna, tendo que desconsiderar o primeiro e o ultimo do dia

Tags: mysql

Estou quebrando a cabeça a alguns dias eu preciso fazer uma query que traga os registros de ponto dos funcionários, mas tenho que ignorar o primeiro e o ultimo registro do dia.
No exemplo eu teria que ignorar as linhas 1 e 10 e comparar a diferença de tempo das linhas 2 e 3, 4 e 5, 6 e 7 e a 8 e 9.
Já agradeço pela atenção.

Minha query está assim:

```
select 
  f.nm_funcionario_nome Nome,
  r.tm_check
from tbl_funcionario f, tbl_registro r
where r.nm_registro = f.nr_cracha
order by 1,2
```

**O resultado é**:

```
Nome    ..................   tm_check
Carlos Kayque A da S    02/05/2019 11:04:40

Carlos Kayque A da S    02/05/2019 11:12:27

Carlos Kayque A da S    02/05/2019 11:13:44

Carlos Kayque A da S    02/05/2019 11:45:01

Carlos Kayque A da S    02/05/2019 12:47:54

Carlos Kayque A da S    02/05/2019 12:54:39

Carlos Kayque A da S    02/05/2019 13:57:32

Carlos Kayque A da S    02/05/2019 13:58:04

Carlos Kayque A da S    02/05/2019 13:58:30

Carlos Kayque A da S    02/05/2019 14:31:35

Carlos Kayque A da S    03/05/2019 07:58:52

Carlos Kayque A da S    03/05/2019 08:11:03
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente eliminar estes dois utilizando sub-selects:

```
select 
  f.nm_funcionario_nome Nome,
  r.tm_check
from tbl_funcionario f, tbl_registro r
where r.nm_registro = f.nr_cracha
and (r.tm_check > (select min(r1.tm_check) from tbl_registro r1 where r1.nr_cracha = r.nr_cracha)
and (r.tm_check < (select max(r2.tm_check) from tbl_registro r2 where r2.nr_cracha = r.nr_cracha)
order by 1,2
```

Talvez você também precise considerar a data.

Comment: Eu tive que fazer alguns ajustes, mas mesmo assim não mudou o resultado.
Trouxe as mesmas informações.


select
  f.nm_funcionario_nome Nome,
  r.tm_check
from tbl_funcionario f, tbl_registro r
where r.nm_registro = f.nr_cracha
and (r.tm_check > (select min(r1.tm_check) from tbl_registro r1 wherer 1.nm_registro = r1.nm_registro))
and (r.tm_check < (select max(r2.tm_check) from tbl_registro r2 where r2.nm_registro = r2.nm_registro))
order by 1,2

Comment: Note que na determinação do máximo e mínimo você referenciou a mesma instância da tabela tbl_registro quando a cláusula WHERE deveria comparar a instância do SELECT mais interno com a instância mais externa. (r.tm_check > (select min(r1.tm_check) from tbl_registro r1 where r1.nm_registro = r.nm_registro)) and 
(r.tm_check < (select max(r2.tm_check) from tbl_registro r2 where r2.nm_registro = r.nm_registro))

Comment: Essa parte deu certo obrigado como eu troquei o campo porque não era o crachá e sim o registro na tabela acabei deixando a referencia a própria sub-consulta.
    Eu gostaria de saber se consigo fazer essa comparação de tempo vou exemplificar no excel.  


     Nome                   tm_check     Resultado  
    Carlos Kayque A da S 02/05/19 11:04   
    Carlos Kayque A da S 02/05/19 11:12 00:07:47  
    Carlos Kayque A da S 02/05/19 11:13 00:01:17  
    Carlos Kayque A da S 02/05/19 11:45 00:31:17  
    Carlos Kayque A da S 02/05/19 12:47 01:02:53